# WEB Api upload file and model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

How can i upload file and model parameters in mvc WEB API 2.

I have following code, which works just fine, if i remove model from the action, but with the model, I am receiving following error.

> "message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is
>   not supported for this resource.",   "exception_message": "No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type
>   'CreateTicketDTO' from content with media type
>   'multipart/form-data'.",

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("api/support/tickets/")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Insert(CreateTicketDTO dto)
        {
           if(dto == null)
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please supply required parameters");


            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            var a = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            foreach (var file in provider.Contents)
            {
                var filename = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('\"');
                var buffer = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                //Do whatever you want with filename and its binaray data.
            }

            using (_ticketService)
            {
                var ticket = await _ticketService.CreateNewTicket(dto);

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ticket);
            }
        }
```

I am creating a post request in Postman.

Comment: change media type  from multipart/form-data to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: that produces following error: Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a content type header starting with 'multipart/'.\r\nParameter name: content",

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369529/how-to-setup-a-webapi-controller-for-multipart-form-data

Comment: @venky, there is no example with model+file in this thread.

Comment: `string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");` `var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider(root);` may it work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729458/webapi-method-that-takes-a-file-upload-and-additional-arguments

Comment: @Venky, my file upload works just fine, but i have a problem with binding file and DTO model at the same time in my action.

Comment: I think the last SO link i shared deals with the similar issue. It suggests to create  formatter which wraps the DTO inside it to be able to pass to HTTP.