# Passing URL or JSON Object with File Upload

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a file upload that is working properly, however, I would like to pass a JSON object that contains other details, such as who created the file, file display name, and file path to upload. Each file type will need to be uploaded in a certain location which I get from the database. Currently my file upload will upload all the files into one location. If this is not possible can I pass the upload path URL in the header only?

HTML

```
       <input name="file" type="file"  (change)="onChange($event)" style="width:80%" [disabled]='showDeleteButton' />
```

component

```
 onChange(event: any) {
        var files = event.srcElement.files;
        this.file = files[0];
        this.fileName = this.file.name;
        console.log('file name ' + this.fileName);
        this._uploadService.makeFileRequest(this.baseURL + 'UploadFiles', [], files).subscribe(() => {
            console.log('file name ' + this.fileName);

        });
```

service

```
    makeFileRequest(url: string, params: string[], files: File[]): Observable<any> {
        return Observable.create((observer: Observer<number>) => {
            let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
                xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);

            }
            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                        observer.complete();
                    } else {
                        observer.error(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            };

            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
    }
```

WebAPI

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("API/FileUpload/UploadFiles")]
    public HttpResponseMessage UploadFiles()
    {
        var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];


        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/upload/"), fileName);
         //   var path = Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/upload/1/1/"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fileName, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            });

            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.Content = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            return response;
        }
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "faild");
    }
```

I would like to pass this object

[image]

or if there is anyway to pass the upload path in the header instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your JSON data into the form Data which you are building in service method,
and access it in Web API.

```
formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);

formData.append("fileInfo" <your JsonData>);
```

[WebAPI method that takes a file upload and additional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729458/webapi-method-that-takes-a-file-upload-and-additional-arguments)